# How get images from .docx to stream with Aspose.Words

Tags: c#, aspose.words

Task is to replace disk operations with streams. When .docx saved to disk - works perfectly. Tried to change using streams.

Have following code:

```
            var options = new HtmlSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Html)
            {
                ImageSavingCallback = new HandleImageSaving()
            };

            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(stream, options);
            stream.Position = 0;
```

---

```
        public class HandleImageSaving : IImageSavingCallback
        {
            void IImageSavingCallback.ImageSaving(ImageSavingArgs e)
            {
                // here e.IsImageAvailable == true 
                // but e.ImageStream == null
            }
        }
```

On doc.Save() it goes callback where imagestream for image is empty - but images exist in word document.

Are there any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.ImageStream allows you to specify the stream where image will be saved. If this property is null, it means image will be saved to disk and not to a stream. You can pass a stream object to this property and image will be saved to that stream object e.g.

```
Stream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
e.ImageStream = imageStream;
```

This will save the image to imageStream object after the **ImageSaving** is called.

I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Have now Session collection of streams inside IImageSavingCallback.ImageSaving. Right after .Save() method executed - do processing images from collection.